# Mock instance attributes without instance

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I would like to test by mocking an instance's attribute, but I do not have access to the instance beforehand. How can I mock the attribute without it? Here is my minimum reproducible code.

```py
# test.py

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

def bar():
    return Foo(1).x + 1

def test_bar(mocker):
    mocker.patch('test.Foo.x', 2)
    assert bar() == 3
```

```sh
$ pytest test.py
FAILED test.py::test_bar - AttributeError: <class 'test.Foo'> does not have the attribute 'x'
```

This makes sense since the `Foo` class doesn't have an `x`, only instances. If I add a kwarg `mocker.patch('test.Foo.x', 2, create=True)` I then get this

```sh
$ pytest test.py
FAILED test.py::test_bar - assert 2 == 3
```

since `Foo.x` will get mocked but overridden when the instance later sets `self.x = x`.

Comment: The test doesn't really make sense. The function `bar()` creates a `Foo(1)`. Why are you testing a situation where it creates a `Foo(2)`? If the parameter passed to `Foo()` can change, then that would provide an opportunity to test what happens. But it can't. Maybe you should be asserting that `Foo(var).x == var` instead.

Comment: @Mark this is intended as an example for a longer more complicated piece of code. I agree that if I were testing this code I would not try to mock it.

Comment: If this instance is not created in the function, then maybe you can pass in a mock. If it *is* created in the instance, then maybe you can mock the conditions that cause it to get created a certain way. In general, you should be testing against the interface, not the internal implementation. If you need to mock internals, it's possible the difficulty in testing is suggesting a refactor of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this kind of test is to mock the entire class, like so:

```
def test_bar(mocker):
  mock_foo = mocker.MagicMock(name='Foo')
  mocker.patch('test.Foo', new=mock_foo)
  mock_foo.return_value.x = 2

  assert bar() == 3
  mock_foo.assert_called_once_with(1)
```

So in this case, you mock the entire `Foo` class.

Then, there is this syntax `mock_foo.return_value.x = 2`: where `mock_foo.return_value` simply means the return object when calling `Foo(1)` - which is your object. Since we mocked the entire class - the `__init__` method does nothing - so you need to set the `x` attribute on your own.

Also note the `mock_foo.assert_called_once_with(1)` - which checks that `Foo(1)` was called with the right parameter.

p.s.

To simplify this kind of mocking, I created a pytest fixture called [pytest-mock-generator](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock-generator/). You can use it to help you create the mocks and asserts.

You start with using the `mg` fixture to analyze your `bar` method so it locates the relevant mocks for you:

```
def test_bar(mocker, mg):
  mg.generate_uut_mocks(bar)
```

When this test method is executed, it generates the following code (prints it to the console and copies it to your clipboard for quick usage):

```
# mocked dependencies
mock_Foo = mocker.MagicMock(name='Foo')
mocker.patch('test.Foo', new=mock_Foo)
```

You then modify the test function and execute the bar method and use the `generate_asserts` capability:

```
def test_bar(mocker, mg):
  # mocked dependencies
  mock_Foo = mocker.MagicMock(name='Foo')
  mocker.patch('test.Foo', new=mock_Foo)

  bar()

  mg.generate_asserts(mock_Foo)
```

This gives you the following output:

```
assert 1 == mock_Foo.call_count
mock_Foo.assert_called_once_with(1)
mock_Foo.return_value.x.__add__.assert_called_once_with(1)
```

You don't need most of it, but you can keep the second line for your assert and the modify the third line so `x` has the right value:

```
def test_bar(mocker):
  mock_foo = mocker.MagicMock(name='Foo')
  mocker.patch('test.Foo', new=mock_foo)
  mock_foo.return_value.x = 2

  assert bar() == 3
  mock_foo.assert_called_once_with(1)
```